# Hide/Show elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following site structure

```
<div id="movies">

     <a href="">
         <div>content</div>
     </a> 
     <a href="">
         <div>content</div>
     </a>
     ...    

</div>
```

There can be up to 50 `a tags` inside `#movies`. I want to show only 10 and reveal another
10 if the user requests it.

So I came up with following jquery code.

```
   var count = $("#movies a").length;

   if(count > 10){
       for(i = 11; i <= count; i++){
          $('#movies a:nth-child('+i+')').hide();   
       }
       $('#more').append('<a>show more</a>');
   }

   $('#more a').click(function(){
       var hidden = $("#movies a").filter(":hidden");

       var count = 0;
       for(element in hidden){
           if(count <= 10){
               element.show();
           }
       }
   });
```

But this gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'show'`. Any ideas why? What do I need to change/add to make the idea work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using some practices which are a little weird:

- Don't use a loop with `nth-child`; just use `$("#movies a").slice(10).hide()`.
- Use `hidden.each(function() { ... })` and not a `for in` loop. Here, you could also use `.slice` to your advantage.
- You don't increment `count`; it's `0` all the time so the `if` clause is always true.

Answer (score 5):

You can't loop using `for(.. in ..)` since that loops over the properties. Use jQuerys each method:

```
hidden.each(function() {
     var element = $(this);
     if(count <= 10)
        element.show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a simpler solution like below,

```
$(function () {
   $("#movies a:gt(9)").hide(); 

   var $moviesA = $('#movies a');
   $('#more a').click(function(){
        var $visibleA = $("#movies a :visible"); //Edit: added a space
        $moviesA.slice($visibleA.length, $visibleA.length + 10).show();
   });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fKuGT/1

Answer (score 0):

`hidden` is a jQuery object.  Don't loop over it using `for..in`.  Use `.each`.

```
hidden.each(function(){
    if(count <= 10){
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```